# Why is the last div in a seperate row overlapping a div in a row above

Tags: bootstrap-4

for the life of me I can't figure out why my `<div class="row">` are overlapping.

I've searched SO, but I can't find the anwser. I've tryed adding `<div class="col-12 w-100"></div>` between different rows but it doesn't help. I've also made sure nothing is `position: absolute`.

Thank you for the help and hopefully explenation =)

https://jsfiddle.net/azjxe3c6/

(the last row, with div col-8 bg-dark is overlaping above)

```
    <div class="row container-fluid justify-content-center box">
        <div class="col-2 box">
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 box">
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 box">
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 box">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 w-100"></div>
    <div class="row container-fluid justify-content-center box">
        <div class="col-4 box r">
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 box b">
        </div>
        <div class="w-100">
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 box b"> <!-- overlapping here -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 box r"> <!-- and here -->
        </div>
        <div class="w-100">
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 box r">
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 box b">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 w-100"></div>
    <div class="row container-fluid justify-content-center box">
        <div class="col-8 box bg-dark">
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.box{
    border: 2px solid black;
    height: 50px; /* this was causing the problem */
}

.r{
    background-color: red;
}

.b{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind... the problem was with a CSS, more specificaly, the box elements had a height which caused the problem.